# Layout transition animation in Flutter

Tags: animation, layout, flutter, transition

Is there a way to do a nice animation between a column layout and a row layout in Flutter?

Specifically I'm trying to implement a backdrop that will show a row with a photo and text when half opened, and a column with the photo and the text when fully opened.

Thanks